# Custom controls in android

Tags: android, custom-controls

I'm new to android and need to create what in .net would be called a custom control. But I have two questions:

1. some articles refer to them as custom controls others custom componnets and other custom widgets.  What should I be looking up?
2. Most questions on this topic are simply refered this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html which is just a view class and is a bit like being handed a chinese dictionary when asked how to write chinese and told everything you need is there. Although true, I'm looking for a simple example something like an odd shapped button with one even attached to it. Surely there must be one such example?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need custom view - look [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). But easier way - customize existing components, by providing specific backgrounds and providing special events.